# What should a person do if he holds differently than the Kohen?

Tags: halacha, korban, machlokes

There were [arguments](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=14&format=text) between Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai in Halachas that were Chayav Korban/Kares.

What happened if a person was a follower of Beis Shammai and sinned unknowingly? According to him, he'd have to bring a Chatas.

He comes to the Beis Hamikdash, and lo and behold, all the Kohanim happened to be Beis Hillel followers. According to them, this sacrifice that he's bringing isn't a sacrifice but Chulin Shenishchetu Be'Azara!!

So they, Leshitaseichem, can't eat it or Shecht it (they can't even say "Safek Olah").

Do the Kohanim have to bring the sacrifice nonetheless?

Comment: I expect that everyone in the Beit Hamikdash would follow the ruling of the Sanhedrin, no?

Comment: @IsaacMoses AFAIR, Machlokesim between Hillel and Shammai lasted some time.

Comment: Maybe a suggestion: get a different Cohen.

Comment: @HachamGabriel What if his time limit is running out and none of the current mishmar hold of Beis Shammai?

Comment: Shmuel What time limit? @Isaac has it right: if you have a question, you ask the Sanhedrin and do what they say. Done.

Comment: @DoubleAA you have three festivals.  http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?tdate=8/14/2013

Comment: @Shmuel Not for a Chattat IIRC. Anything under Bal Teacheir they can always bring as a safek.

Comment: -1 mi ma nafshach, if halacha remains the same by the time we build BHM3, then we follow beis hillel.  If moshiach comes and verifies the opinion that we're all supposed to follow beis shammai now that moshiach is here, then we'll all follow beis shammai.  Either way, the question can never actually happen.

Comment: @Jake Second Beis Hamikdash

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It was destroyed 1,944 years ago.  Therefore, the situation in the question can never actually happen.  You want to know what *would have happened* back then?  Anyone who didn't follow the mesorah in the BHM, died.  Tzidukim priests died after offering the ketores wrong, Romans appointed non-kohanim as kohen gadol, but they died every Yom Kippur.  It's a moot point what would have been 1,900 years ago, and it won't be an issue in BHM3, may we build it today.

Comment: @Jake not if the sin wasn't chayav misah

Comment: @Jake And they didn't always die that moment

Comment: @Jake I don't know why it can't still be interesting to find out?

Comment: What's the saying, when by Hillel do as Hillel, when by Shammai do as Shammai? (...or maybe it was Rov and Shmuel?)